# How do I apply permanent style changes to a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm trying to apply permanent style changes to my data frame (by using `inplace=True`) after using the `dataset.style.format()` function because I want adding zeros to some columns.

I put `inplace=True` inside the format function:

```py
dataset.style.format(
    {
        'Size': '{:,.1f}',
        'RetailPrice': '{:,.2f}'
    },
    inplace=True
)
```

But I get the following error:

```py
TypeError: format() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'
```

Is there any way around this?

I was expecting the `inplace=True` to work so that it would apply permanent changes to the data frame, and then I could export the `CSV`.

Comment: This is not possible, `style` generates a special object, not a DataFrame. You can however chain `to_csv` to export the style (well, not all styles as csv, rather as excel or html).

Comment: Oh right ok would it be something like this, dataset.to_csv("NEWSKU.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False, float_format='%.1f') Or how would go about doing it

Comment: `dataset.style.format({'Size': "{:,.1f}", 'RetailPrice': "{:,.2f}" }).to_csv(…)`

Comment: Thanks I changed the code to this: dataset.style.format({'Size': "{:,.1f}", 'RetailPrice': "{:,.2f}" }).to_csv("NEWSKU.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False) - But I get AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_csv' when I run it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `to_excel`

Comment: I tried that but I get a ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'csv'

Comment: code is not format properly..

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit more

Comment: A DataFrame's `style` attribute returns a [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html), which is for visualizing the DataFrame's data in HTML. It doesn't modify the DataFrame itself. I don't think what you're after is possible with this tool.

Comment: Please, add the attempts you made to the body of your question, and add a sample of the input data you are using. That will make it easier for us to help you.